# What does this scale means?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, svm

I tried to see what is the most contributing features in a dataset by using a code that I found. The code as follows

```
def f_importances(coef, names):
    imp = coef
    imp,names = zip(*sorted(zip(imp,names)))
    plt.barh(range(len(names)), imp, align='center')
    plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
    plt.show()

features_names = ['text', 'jumlah kata', 'jam']

n_classes = 3
n_features = len(features_names)

clf_coef_ = np.random.randint(1, 30, size=(int(0.5*n_classes*(n_classes-1)), n_features))

f_importances(clf_coef_.sum(axis=0), features_names)
```

From that code, I got the following result

[image: Most Contributing features]

My questions are

1. what does that the number in X plane means? There are 10, 20, 30, and so on. I cannot ask the uploader.
2. It seems to be random. How do I make it not random? For example I want to use all of the data

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
features_names = ['text', 'jumlah kata', 'jam']

n_classes = 3
n_features = len(features_names)

clf_coef_ = np.random.randint(1, 30, size=(int(0.5*n_classes*(n_classes-1)), n_features))

# clf_coef_ is a 3*3 random matrix
# each of its value is in range(1,30)
# for example
# [[22  4 22]
#  [15 18  8]
#  [23 22 13]]

f_importances(clf_coef_.sum(axis=0), features_names)
# clf_coef_.sum(axis=0)
# summary on columns
#
# [22+15+23,  4+18+22,   22+8+13]
# then it will become [60, 44, 43]

# f_importances finally will take arguments:
# [60,44,43] & ['text', 'jumlah kata', 'jam']
# sequence is corresponded
# sorted by values (this may differ with your codes, due to random values)
# jam  --> 43
# jumlah kata  --> 44
# text --> 60
# then plot will be got
```

To answer your second question, you can make `clf_coef_` be not defined as a random array.